# Loops and Tables

Tags: tables, loops

I'm trying to use LaTex to produce our family diary for next year. It's a page per week with a column for each person.

I have the basic layout working:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a5paper, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=2cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{advdate}    % Advancing/saving dates
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}   % Dates formatting
\usepackage{datenumber} % Counters for dates
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newdateformat{mydate}{\shortdayofweekname{\day}{\month}{\year} \twodigit\THEDAY{} \shortmonthname[\THEMONTH]}

\newcommand{\headerrow}{\hline & Me & My Wife & Son & Daughter\\ \hline}
\newcommand{\dayrow}[1]{\AdvanceDate[#1] \mydate\today & & & &\\[2.2cm] \hline}
\newcommand{\weektable}{
    \newpage
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \headerrow{}
    \dayrow{0}
    \dayrow{1}
    \dayrow{2}
    \dayrow{3}
    \dayrow{4}
    \dayrow{5}
    \dayrow{6}
    \end{tabularx}  
}


\SetDate[05/01/2015]
\begin{document}
    \weektable{}
\end{document}
```

but it's ugly!!

I've tried using a loop to avoid the repetition in \weektable, but I'm falling foul of loops within tables and cannot get it to work.

I've also tried adding a parameter to \weektable so I can produce several weeks at once, but I can't work out how pass the result of a calculation into the command.

I know these are both similar to other questions but, despite reading everywhere I've found on here, I'm stuck and would appreciate some help!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick improvement for a working version, but it does **not address** some issues (i.e. table design etc.)

Use for example the `forloop` package to make the full year table...

However, since the OP uses `\AdvanceDate` in a table cell (a group), the actual day is not advanced after a week table is finished, so this has to be done after the `tabularx` environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a5paper, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=2cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{advdate}    % Advancing/saving dates
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}   % Dates formatting
\usepackage{datenumber} % Counters for dates
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{forloop}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newdateformat{mydate}{\shortdayofweekname{\day}{\month}{\year} \twodigit\THEDAY{} \shortmonthname[\THEMONTH]}



\newcommand{\headerrow}{\hline & Me & My Wife & Son & Daughter\\ \hline}
\newcommand{\dayrow}[1]{\AdvanceDate[#1] \mydate\today & & & &\\[2.2cm] \hline}
\newcommand{\weektable}{
    \newpage
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \headerrow{}
    \dayrow{0}
    \dayrow{1}
    \dayrow{2}
    \dayrow{3}
    \dayrow{4}
    \dayrow{5}
    \dayrow{6}
    \end{tabularx}  
    \AdvanceDate[7]%
}



\SetDate[05/01/2015]

\newcounter{weeks}%
\begin{document}
   \forloop{weeks}{1}{\value{weeks} < 53}{%
    \weektable{}

}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that avoids the need for any calculation rather nicely!

Comment: and yes, I know the table design isn't great, but let's just say I'm working to a specification defined by a higher authority!

Comment: @Owen: Your wife? ;-)

Comment: Yep - a.k.a "Senior Management"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xparse` and `expl3` for repeating the task:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a5paper, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=2cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{advdate}    % Advancing/saving dates
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}   % Dates formatting
\usepackage{datenumber} % Counters for dates
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newdateformat{mydate}{%
  \shortdayofweekname{\day}{\month}{\year} % space
  \twodigit\THEDAY{} % space
  \shortmonthname[\THEMONTH]% no space
}

\newcommand{\headerrow}{\hline & Me & My Wife & Son & Daughter\\ \hline}
\newcommand{\dayrow}[1]{\AdvanceDate[#1] \mydate\today & & & &\\[2.2cm] \hline}
\newcommand{\printweektable}{%
    \newpage\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \headerrow
    \dayrow{0}
    \dayrow{1}
    \dayrow{2}
    \dayrow{3}
    \dayrow{4}
    \dayrow{5}
    \dayrow{6}
    \end{tabularx}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\weektable}{O{1}m}
 {
  \SetDate[#2]
  \computedayofweek{\day}{\month}{\year}
  % always start on Monday
  \AdvanceDate[
    \int_eval:n { 2 - \dayofweek \int_compare:nT { \dayofweek == 1 } { -7 } }
  ]
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \printweektable }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\weektable[4]{04/01/2015}

\end{document}
```

The date can be arbitrary, the week will always start on a Monday such that the “starting” day is included.

For example, 4 January 2015 will be a Sunday, so the first page will start from Monday 29 December.

The optional argument tells how many weeks are to be generated (default one).

[image]

Comment: Very nice! That avoids one potential cockup and a whole heap of wasted paper